# date conversion and math in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, date, split, duration

I have two values coming in, a string in the form StartTime `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and a Duration in the form `HH:MM:SS`.  from these two values I need to determine the endTime and put it in the same format as the StartTime.

I have tried to make something like

```
startTimeArray:Array = StartTime.split(/[ -:]/);
var date:Date = new Date(startTimeArray[0], startTimeArray[1]-1, startTimeArray[2], startTimeArray[3], startTimeArray[4], startTimeArray[5] );
```

but the split of course results in strings and not numbers and I can't figure how to convert all these sections of the time into numbers, and following that I do not see a way to apply math by adding the Duration Date object to the StartTime Date object if I am able to get them properly converted.

Am I going down a good path here? if so, how can I convert an array of strings to numbers and how can I add the duration to starttime? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const start:String = "2011-04-03 01:39:48";
const startArray:Array = start.split(/[: -]/g);
var startDate:Date = new Date(
    startArray[0], startArray[1]-1, startArray[2],
    startArray[3], startArray[4], startArray[5]
);
const duration:String = "02:10:10";
const durationArray:Array = duration.split(/:/g);
var durationDate:Date = new Date();
durationDate.setTime(
    durationArray[0] * 3600000 + /* hour = 60m * 60s * 1000ms */
    durationArray[1] * 60000 + /* minute = 60s * 1000ms */
    durationArray[2] * 1000 /* second = 1000ms */
);
var finalDate:Date = new Date();
finalDate.setTime(startDate.time + durationDate.time);
trace(startDate);
trace(durationDate.time);
trace(finalDate);
```

Outputs:

```
Sun Apr 3 01:39:48 GMT-0300 2011
7810000
Sun Apr 3 03:49:58 GMT-0300 2011
```

Comment: looks good!  the only problem is for some reason the end date right now for me is turning out to be a month later than it should be. i don't see how that's possible but i'll see what i can figure out

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry! That's because months range from 0 to 11. I updated to fix it: `startArray[1]-1`

Comment: oh awesome!  i actually had that in my initial go-through so i should have noticed it as well..

Answer (score 1):

You will want to split the date and time first and then work from there with the arrays.

```
var date_:String = StartTime.substring(0,StartTimet.indexOf(" "));
var time_:String = StartTime.substring(StartTime.indexOf(" ")+1, StartTime.length);
trace(date_); // YYYY-MM-DD
trace(time_); // HH:MM:SS
```

Then split your date into an array

```
var date_array:Array = StartTime.split("-");
```

Cast the elements of the array with `Number`

Then do the same for time but use ":" for the split.
Duration can be split the same way. Then just use normal addition after casting.

```
var d:Date = new Date(year,month,date,hour,minutes,seconds);
var d_added:Date = new Date(year,month,date,hour+duration_hour,
              minutes+duration_minutes,seconds+duration_seconds);
```

Comment: will have a go with that. is there a way to cast an entire array as numbers, or do i have to loop through it?
I dunno how its going to work properly with straight math if you have 1:59:00 + 1:02:33 or whatnot..

Comment: @Damon Yeah I would just go though. There could be other ways, I am not sure about that.It is only three per type (date(3), time(3)). Then you can have something like `var d_added:Date = new Date(year,month,date,hour+duration_hour,minutes+duration_minutes,seconds+duration_seconds)`. I will update the above with an example.